# How can I convert my Palm OS Calendar to Thunderbird/Lighting (/ics) format?

Tags: calendar, palm, palm-desktop

I have an old copy of my PalmOS calendar, but no longer have the device.  How can I import these into Thunderbird/Lighting or convert them to .ics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot, at least not directly.  Palm's Desktop application only supports exporting in their own Date Book Archive (.dba).  Thunderbird/Lighting uses the standard (.ics - RFC 2445/RFC 5545) format.

**[palm2ical](http://hepunx.rl.ac.uk/~adye/software/palm/palm2ical/)** is a tool that runs on Windows, Mac, Linux.  It's self contained.

The next problem was how to get the DatebookDB.PDB or CalendarDB-PDat.PDB file if you no longer have your PDA.

The page talks about:

Extracting the PDB file from your Palm

1. Easy method — using an SD Card or LifeDrive
2. Harder method — using HotSync
3. Extracting the PDB file without your Palm (by using the Palm Simulator).

Once you have the database file (.pdb), you can run the utility:

Examples:

```
palm2ical
palm2ical -o CalendarDB-PDat.ics CalendarDB-PDat.PDB
palm2ical CalendarDB-PDat.PDB > CalendarDB-PDat.ics
```

There are also other tools listed under "Similar Programs" although I have not tested them.

Comment: A note: we used an online converter that converted to Excel/csv, and imported to Google calendar. I think the Palm calendar was very simplistic when it came to daylight savings. Check times on any future appointments.